# Is zero a possible ManagedThreadID

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am keeping track of a collection of threads using the ManagedThreadIDs. This allows my context objects to know which threads are doing work for them.

However I have come to a point where I would like the context objects to be able to test if *any* thread is doing work for them. As the IDs are just integers I could test for the value being zero. But is zero a possible thread ID??

Obviously if it is, then testing to see if a thread is "assigned" to do some context work will mean this quick check is no good and I need to check the threads (to see what contexts they are all using) instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undocumented.  If the SSCLI20 implementation is still accurate for the version of the CLR you are using, odds are very high, then it's okay to assume that 0 won't be a valid ManagedThreadId.  The internal IdDispenser helper class in clr/src/vm/threads.h generates managed thread IDs with its NewId() function.  Which uses a return value of 0 as an error indication.

Comment: How does one find this stuff out? I had been scouring MSDN Library for *any* in depth info on threadIds (among other similar things), but it always seems very light on relevant details...

Comment: As I said, it is undocumented.  So you ask at SO of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be worried about a zero. It is reserved for the idle thread.

Comment: That's not a managed thread, Thread.ManagedThreadId != Windows thread ID.